# How to return parsed result from fetch pipe feeding sax parser (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node.js code that fetches an XML feed, pipes it into a sax parser and extracts the data I need into a JS Object.

The code, at its simplest level looks like this.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const sax = require('sax')

function fetchAndParse(url)
{

  const saxStream = require("sax").createStream(strict, {normalize: true, trim: true})
  const desiredData = []

  saxStream.on("error", function (err) {
      ...
  }).on("opentag", function (node) {
      ...
  }).on("cdata", function(t) {
      ...
  }).on("text", function(t) {
      ...
  }).on("closetag", function (nodeName) {
      ...
  }).on("end", function() {
    console.log("END", desiredData)
  })

  fetch(url)
  .then(
    res => { res.body.pipe(saxStream) }
  )
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to turn this into an `async` function and just use `await` when calling it, but at the moment I'm not seeing how to get the data out of here when it completes because the only place I've been able to access the finished data is in the `on("end")` function. I think I'm missing something really basic here.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the `sax` library before so I'm not entirely sure what its API looks like, but you *should* be able to just return a promise that resolves with the data you want.

Something like this (note: I didn't test this):

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const sax = require("sax");

function fetchAndParse(url) {
  const saxStream = require("sax").createStream(strict, {
    normalize: true,
    trim: true,
  });
  const desiredData = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    saxStream
      .on("error", function (err) {
        reject(err);
      })
      .on("opentag", function (node) {
        // ...
      })
      .on("cdata", function (t) {
        // ...
      })
      .on("text", function (t) {
        // ...
      })
      .on("closetag", function (nodeName) {
        // ...
      })
      .on("end", function () {
        resolve(desiredData);
      });

    fetch(url).then((res) => {
      res.body.pipe(saxStream);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but the parser doesn't seem to have a way to return a data value, probably because it's designed in a way that it can only pass along the input value to pipe it to another operation. I think the problem is really this fundamental nature of the parser, so I can neither return a Promise nor the ```desiredData``` value.

I ended up reworking this so that I do a complete fetch and then don't pipe the value into the parser. It has another form takes in a string. I can put an ```await``` on the call to that form of the sax parser.

Answer (score 0):

The sax parser has 2 forms: one that takes in a pipe and another that takes in a string. The piped version can only emit the pipe stream, in case you want to pass it along to something else, and there appears to be no way to override this behavior.

As a solution, use the parser as written, and invoke it as shown below. This requires fetching the entire document, unfortunately. Otherwise consider using another parser.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const sax = require('sax')

function fetchAndParse(url)
{

  const saxStream = require("sax").createStream(strict, {normalize: true, trim: true})
  const desiredData = []

  saxStream.on("error", function (err) {
    // Rest of code from question goes here
  }

  const res = await fetch(url)
  const rss = await res.text()
  await saxStream.write(rss)
  return desiredData;
}
```